# What's the meaning of `SUR`?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I saw a slogan:

```
​NO HELP WITH BIG SUR HERE.
```

what's the meaning of it? I just don't understand `SUR`.

---

**EDIT-01**

[image]

Comment: "Big Sur" can refer to a number of things, starting with "a region of the Central California coast" (Wikipedia).   Where did you see that slogan?

Comment: thanks your response. In a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS Big Sur (version 11.0) is the next major release of macOS, Apple Inc.'s operating system for Macintosh computers. It is the successor to macOS Catalina (version 10.15) and was announced at Apple’s Worldwide Developers Conference on June 22, 2020, with public beta release scheduled for July and general release projected for fall. It is named after the coastal region of Big Sur in the Central Coast of California. Clearly, no help was available for that version.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia,

[Wikipedia "Big Sur" etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Sur#Etymology)

"The Spanish referred to the vast and relatively unexplored coastal region to the south of Monterey as *el país grande del sur*, meaning "the big country of the south". This was often shortened to *el sur grande* (the big south)."

So, "sur" is Spanish for "south".

I don't know why that phrase would appear in a piece of software, except that it might refer to the name of another piece of software, since the example you posted shows three other location references: "Catalina", "Mojave", and "High Sierra".

Comment: It may mean version below a fixed point.

Comment: That makes sense.